# How to solve process timing issues with Swift when working with iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, swift, macos, timing

I am facing with this specific timing issue sometimes. I am using timer to overcome of that but using timer trashing my code structure.

"The timing issue" is that. We are creating functions and call them one after other but some functions takes longer time finishing their job and when other function is called before the previous one has finished its job
that causing  problems.

As I stated at the beginning  I can solve that rare issue  by using timer after this functions causing issue but looking for better solution which is not going to disturb code structure.

The last function causing the problem was the one below.
When it is called by user action such as touching a button there is
no issue.
But when it is called by an other function it casing above mentioned problem.

```
   func getImageOfView (viewName: NSView) -> NSImage {


    let width   = viewName.frame.size.width
    let height  = viewName.frame.size.height





    let pageSize = CGSizeMake(width ,height);

    let image  = NSImage.init(size: pageSize)

    image.lockFocus()


    let contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.graphicsPort 

    let context: CGContextRef = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(contextPointer!)).takeUnretainedValue()



    viewName.layer!.renderInContext(context)

    image.unlockFocus()



    return image
```

}

Comment: I think you should use completion handlers in this case.

Comment: You should show an example of your functions

Comment: If you are running the functions in parallel threads, you could use dispatch groups. Otherwise iOS geeks suggestion is a good one

Comment: @Wain, I believe  that functions themselves  are irrelevant but generally, Those functions causing trouble are functions dealing  with graphics.

Comment: Timers are never a good solution for task synchronisation, but you need to provide more information on the functions and their dependency for anyone to suggest concrete solutions.

Comment: I am confused because using _dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(
                        Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.rawValue), 0)) {  myFunction() }_ is solved the problem instead of _dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(
                        Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.rawValue), 0)){ myFunction() }_

Comment: @Hope you're kind of right, i don't care what the function actually does, but i'm interested in how it does it, how it's called, what it returns, if it's asynchronous, that thread it runs on... all this information goes into how you deal with it

Comment: @Wain, I added the function because mostly, you can not see the stupid mistake you make, yourself !